# Let's be printed the matter

Tags: grammaticality, contractions

> Let's be printed the matter.

This sentence is wrong and it sounds odd.

But grammatically what is the error in this sentence? Is there any specific format for **Let's**? I have read on a website that "Let is followed by an infinitive without 'to' ".

Comment: The sentence is *so* "odd" I'm not sure what you intend it to mean. ***Let the matter be printed*** is syntactically valid, but again, the semantics are so weird it's hard to understand why anyone would say anything like that. But ***Let the matter be discussed*** and ***Let's discuss the matter*** are perfectly natural utterances. Is there any reason why your "invalid" example couldn't be changed to ***Let's be discussed the matter***?

Comment: I think the other problem is that you have two objects. The "be" means it's passive, but you don't know whether you're meant to be printing "us" or "the matter". You need to remove one. It would still be very odd (like FumbleFingers says) but "Let's be printed" or "Let the matter be printed" can can actually be understood. (I'm thinking of some sort of ink stamp for the first one!)

Comment: What was your context? For me, the sentence makes no semantic sense whatsoever. You can't print a matter. And you certainly would not say: Let's be printed + direct object.

Answer (score 2):

“Let’s” is a contraction for “let us.”

Thus, assuming novels converse with one another before being printed, a not-yet-printed novel might say to one or more other not-yet-printed novels,

> Let’s be printed

That is perfectly grammatical, however odd the thought.

No one would think odd

> Let’s be photographed together.

Now consider the following sentence:

> Let the book be printed

This sentence is in standard word order: it has an imperative verb, “let,” with an implied subject, and the verb’s object, “book,” properly follows that verb and precedes the modifying passive infinitive “be printed.”

> Let be printed the book

is simply invalid word order in English.

> Let the matter be printed

is grammatical but makes no sense. Matters are not books or papers that are printed.

> Let’s be printed the matter

mixes up “let’s” and “let,” violates grammatical word order, and uses the word “matter” when something else was meant. It sounds odd because it is simultaneously ungrammatical and nonsensical.